# Return all Users, even those who don't fit my criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to return a full list of people, but only show data in the Document type column where the document type is 'Security Clearance Report'

I'm quite new to SQL and trying to figure this stuff out. 
The aim is so management can easily see who has got this doc type, but also who hasn't.

```
SELECT papf.person_id
     , (ppnf.first_name||' '||ppnf.last_name)                                    e_name
     , dor.document_name
     , dor_type.document_type
     , TO_CHAR(dor.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')                                  dor_issue_date
FROM per_all_people_f                                         papf
     , per_person_names_f                                       ppnf
     , hr_document_types_vl                                     dor_type
     , hr_documents_of_record                                   dor
 WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
   AND papf.person_id                      = ppnf.person_id 
   AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ppnf.effective_start_date AND ppnf.effective_end_date
   AND ppnf.name_type                      = 'GLOBAL'
   AND papf.person_id                      = dor.person_id (+)
   AND dor_type.document_type_id           = dor.document_type_id
   AND dor_type.document_type = 'Security Clearance Report'
ORDER BY e_name DESC
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Is it possible for a person to have more than one document where the type is 'Security Clearance Report'? If so, do you want to list the document_name for all those documents?

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted elsewhere here, this sort of thing is much simpler to do if you use ANSI style joins.

Even so, it is a little tricky because you want to `LEFT JOIN` your list of people to an `INNER JOIN` between `HR_DOCUMENTS_OF_RECORD` and `HR_DOCUMENT_TYPES_VL`.  That is, for each person, you want the documents of record that are type "Security Clearance Report", if any exist.

Here is how you do that:

```
SELECT papf.person_id
     , (ppnf.first_name||' '||ppnf.last_name)                                    e_name
     , dor.document_name
     , dor_type.document_type
     , TO_CHAR(dor.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')                                  dor_issue_date
FROM per_all_people_f  papf
INNER JOIN per_person_names_f ppnf ON ppnf.person_id = papf.person_id
           AND ppnf.name_type                      = 'GLOBAL'
           AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ppnf.effective_start_date AND NVL(ppnf.effective_end_date,SYSDATE)
LEFT JOIN ( hr_documents_of_record dor 
INNER JOIN hr_document_types_vl dor_type ON dor_type.document_type_id = dor.document_type_id
           AND dor_type.document_type = 'Security Clearance Report'  ) ON dor.person_id = papf.person_id
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND NVL(papf.effective_end_date,SYSDATE)
ORDER BY e_name DESC;
```

Note the `INNER JOIN` between `DOR` and `DOR_TYPE` is in parentheses and the `LEFT JOIN` condition is *after* the parentheses.

If you just naively `LEFT JOIN` everything and any people have documents of record besides security clearance reports, you'll get too many rows.

Comment: I get a "Missing Right Parenthesis" error.
Nested Joins seems complicated to me *worried emoji*

Comment: I cannot help you with a syntax error like "missing parentheses" unless you post your exact query.  You can avoid the nested joins by making a view or a `WITH` clause that inner joins `HR_DOCUMENTS_OF_RECORD` and `HR_DOCUMENT_TYPES_VL` and the left joint to _that_ in your main query, if you like that better.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT *
 FROM per_all_people_f papf
 JOIN  hr_documents_of_record  dor
   ON  papf.person_id =  dor.person_id
 LEFT JOIN hr_document_types_vl dor_type
   ON dor_type.document_type_id = dor.document_type_id
  AND dor_type.document_type = 'Security Clearance Report'
```

Comment: It's not so simple as that.  Your query will exclude people who have no documents of record at all.  If you convert the join to `HR_DOCUMENTS_OF_RECORD` to a `LEFT JOIN`, you will get one row for every document of record for each person.

Comment: I dont have the db schema I just want to show how the `LEFT JOIN` will show row matching and not matching. Also showing how the `JOIN` work instead of the old where method. @MatthewMcPeak

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to return a full list of people,

To get the full list of people, I would remove  the requirement 
`AND dor_type.document_type = 'Security Clearance Report'`

> The aim is so management can easily see who has got this doc type, but also who hasn't.

In your select, you can do this:

`, DECODE(dor_type.document_type, 'Security Clearance Report', dor_type.document_type ,null)`

For any row where the document_type is the one you want, it will show it. For the others, it will just show null.

```
SELECT papf.person_id
 , (ppnf.first_name||' '||ppnf.last_name)                                    e_name
 , dor.document_name
 , DECODE(dor_type.document_type, 'Security Clearance Report', dor_type.document_type ,null)
 , TO_CHAR(dor.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')                                  dor_issue_date
FROM per_all_people_f                                         papf
 , per_person_names_f                                       ppnf
 , hr_document_types_vl                                     dor_type
 , hr_documents_of_record                                   dor
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
AND papf.person_id                      = ppnf.person_id 
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ppnf.effective_start_date AND ppnf.effective_end_date
AND ppnf.name_type                      = 'GLOBAL'
AND papf.person_id                      = dor.person_id (+)
AND dor_type.document_type_id           = dor.document_type_id
ORDER BY e_name DESC
```