# SQL Oracle code - not getting unique values

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the below code which I'm wanting to give me a unique list of **papf.person_number** and then it should be giving me the creation date of the **Security Clearance Report** where one exists (which seems to be working). 
My problem is it's returning multiple lines (between 3 and 6) per unique **papf.person_number**. 
I know it might be asking a lot when you don't know the database, but hoping you can give me some suggestions of where I'm going wrong with my AND statements (company standard seems to be to use conditions rather than joins).

```
SELECT papf.person_number
     , (ppnf.first_name||' '||ppnf.last_name)                  full_name
     , paam.assignment_type 
     ,(SELECT * FROM 
        (Select TO_CHAR(dor.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        From    hr_documents_of_record                         dor
        WHERE   dor_type.document_type = 'Security Clearance Report'
        AND     papf.person_id                      = dor.person_id
        AND     dor_type.document_type_id           = dor.document_type_id
        Order BY dor.creation_date DESC
        ) 
        WHERE ROWNUM=1)                                        "Security Clearance Report"          
  FROM   per_all_people_f                       papf
        ,per_person_names_f                     ppnf 
        ,hr_documents_of_record                 dor 
        ,hr_document_types_vl                   dor_type 
        ,per_all_assignments_m                  paam 

WHERE   papf.person_id = ppnf.person_id 
    AND ppnf.person_id = dor.person_id 
    AND dor.person_id = paam.person_id
    AND SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
    AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ppnf.effective_start_date AND ppnf.effective_end_date
    AND SYSDATE BETWEEN paam.effective_start_date AND paam.effective_end_date
    AND paam.effective_latest_change = 'Y'
    AND paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
    AND ppnf.name_type                      = 'GLOBAL'
    AND paam.assignment_status_type         = 'ACTIVE'
    AND paam.assignment_type                IN('E','C','N','P')
    AND dor_type.document_type_id = dor.document_type_id
Order by full_name
```

Comment: There are 5 tables involved. There is little chance that anyone can tell where data duplications is happening...

Comment: This seems pretty similar to [the question you asked two day's ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58594521/146325). Did that answer not help you? Either way please explain what is different about this question. Also, providing table structures and sample data, plus required output derived from that sample will increase your chances of getting a timely and helpful answer.

Comment: First, I would recommend using ANSI formatted joins in the future.  For me personally, it helps me make sure that I haven't missed a value in my join criteria and end up with a partial Cartesian.  Second, the best thing may be to break your query apart and rebuild it one table at a time until you get duplicate rows.  There seem to be a few tables you list which have the potential for multiple rows...like HR documents.

Comment: If "company standard seems to be to use conditions rather than joins" I would complain loudly; that is pretty ridiculous.  Do they also implement constraints in the application instead of the database? The optimizer can usually do a better job with joins instead of conditions.